# A confusing question about the expectation of $e^{3X/4}$,which is a continuous function.

Tags: probability, expectation, density-function

I got this problem from John.E.Freund's Mathematical_Statistics_with_Applications.

the question is,

If X has the probability density

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^x& x>0\\
0& \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$find the expected value of $g(X) = e^{3X/4}$.

In chapter 4 it shows that the expectation is $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{3x/4}e^{-x}dx$,

I have no idea why it's $$e^{3x/4}e^{-x}$$ here, shouldn't it be $$e^{3x/4}e^{x}? $$

I checked the 7th and 8th editions of the book, and both show the first version, I think there must be something missed in my mind.Could you please help me to solve the question? Thanks very much. ：）

Comment: I do not have the book you mention but are you sure you are reading $f$ right? If it were a pdf, then $\int_{D}{f(x)dx}=1$

Comment: thanks friend, it should be $$e^{-x}$$, I'm sure it's right, it's a horrible edition mistake but the  auditor didn't correct it through the two editions, it shouldn't be forgiven. Thanks my friend very much, thanks.:)